# Kinvey on IOS Simulator issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, authentication, kinvey

I am working on a project in Xcode using objective c.  I am implementing kinvey for login purposes and found that there is an error when on login and registration, both manual and auto-generated, on the simulator.  The odd thing is that the error only happens on iOS 8.3; it works fine on 9.0 or 9.3.

In 8.3 I receive the following error:

> domain: @"KinveyError" - code: 406
>
> @"Kinvey requires `application/json` as the Content-Type of the response"

I have tried resetting the simulator, restarting Xcode, restarting the mac, updating to the latest kinvey module, and even using an old kinvey module.  The error persists, and I am not sure what else I should try.

Answer (score 1):

Does the Statusshare sample app work for you?
Here is the link: http://devcenter.kinvey.com/ios/samples/statusshare

It does have new user account creation and login. I tried it on an iphone6/ iOS 8.3 simulator and Kinveykit version (1.40.7) and the sample worked fine for me.

Thanks,
Pranav
Kinvey Support

Comment: Actually I think the issue is that the simulator seems to be stuck on no connection.